Does $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k} f(x+ \frac{ka}{n}) \to f(x+pa)$ as $n \to \infty$ when $f$ is strictly increasing and concave?
Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is strictly increasing and strictly concave.
Can we show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k} f(x+ \frac{ka}{n}) \to f(x+pa)$ as $n \to \infty$ given $p \in (0,1)$ and $a \geq 0$?
The summation is upper bounded by $f(x+pa)$ as we can see using Jensen. However, I would like to know if it can grow till that point.

What are $p$ and $a$ here?

@VarunVejalla Added.
